# Adding custom button next to "Add to Cart" Button" Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, button, woocommerce

Hi guys im trying to add custom button next to "Add to Cart" button. I added it but i want to change button link for every product how can i do that here is my code: ( i took from another question, it works )

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'add_a_custom_button', 5 );

function add_a_custom_button() {
   global $product;

   // Not for variable and grouped products that doesn't have an "add to cart" button
   if( $product->is_type('variable') || $product->is_type('grouped') ) return;

   // Output the custom button linked to the product
   echo '<div style="margin-bottom:10px;">
    <a class="button custom-button" href="' . esc_attr( $product->get_permalink() ) . '">' . __('View product') . '</a>
</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

Create a new Wordpress custom field for the pages you want to use a custom url link on:

Custom field name: nothanks_link_redirect

Custom field value: https://yourlink.com

Tweak as you need and put this in your child theme's functions.php :

```
/** WooCommerce custom field - 'No Thanks' Button **/
function nothanks_redirect_button() {
   global $post;
   $product_id = $post->ID;

   $NoThanksLinkRedirectValue =  get_post_meta($product_id,'nothanks_link_redirect',true);
   if(!$NoThanksLinkRedirectValue) return;
   echo '<a class="nothanks-button" style="margin-left: 20px" href="'.$NoThanksLinkRedirectValue.'" target="_self">No Thanks</a>';
}
add_action('woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button','nothanks_redirect_button');
```

Enjoy!